# Retrieve the UIImage taken with takePicture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Currently, I can retrieve the picture taken with takePicture in the function imagePickerController, but I want to use it outside of this function, and when I try to make a global variable to use this UIImage, I don't have any picture.
So how can I use this UIImage ?

My code :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)aPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    screenshot = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

and I use it there :

```
NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver/test.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"tmp.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
NSLog(@"responseStatusString %@",[request responseString]);
```

screenshot is my global variable and I receive a blank image on my server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you retaining the UIImage?

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are implementing UIImagePickerControllerDelegate? If so, when imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: is called, you can get the image out of the dictionary passed in using:

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

If you want to retain the image, declare a property with retain for your viewcontroller class, and set it:

```
self.image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Comment: How can I do to make your second option ?

Comment: That's basic objective-c. Declare a member variable in your .h UIImage *image. Declare a property for that member @property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image. Then @synthesize *image in your .m. http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-properties-setters-and-dot-syntax.html

Comment: Are you using the built in editor for images? If so you need to use a different constant ie UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage I believe. What are you doing with the image after you are retaining it?